# Terraform with Azure gives circular dependency

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to use the Azure provider to provision the infrastructure. I've got the same process working via the AzureCLI, but want to move to Terraform.

Unfortunately, I've hit a circular dependency that I can't seem to resolve. I've got the following items.

1. Cognitive service with a generated API key
2. AppService with a SystemAssigned identity;
3. Keyvault, with the identity assigned in (2) given read access;
4. Keyvault secret with the API key generated in (1).
5. AppService in (2) needs to be updated with the secret Id generated in (3). - Problem.

Now: I need to set the configuration of the AppService to reference the secret Id that I generate when adding to the vault, but I can't.

Is there a way to edit these values so the configuration can be set up in parts? ie provision x then modify?

Edit: My Terraform file is below:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "=1.28.0"
}

variable "TENANT_ID" {
  type = string
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
    name = "resourceGroup1"
    location = "australiaeast"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "plan" {
  name = "resourceGroup1"
  location = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  kind = "Linux"

  sku {
    tier = "Basic"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "cognitive" {
  name = "resourceGroup1-cognitive"
  location = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  kind = "ComputerVision"

  sku {
    name = "S0"
    tier = "Standard"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name = "resourceGroup1-keyvault"
  location = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  tenant_id = var.TENANT_ID

  sku {
    name = "standard"
  }

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = "${azurerm_app_service.api.identity.0.tenant_id}"
    object_id = "${azurerm_app_service.api.identity.0.principal_id}"

    secret_permissions = [ "get" ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "keyvault-apikey" {
  name = "AzureComputerVisionApiKey"
  value = "${azurerm_cognitive_account.cognitive.primary_access_key}"
  key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "api" {
  name = "resourceGroup1-api"
  location = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.plan.id}"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  app_settings = {
    "ASPNETCORE_AzureComputerVisionApiKey" = "THIS IS A NORMAL SECRET VALUE"
  }
}
```

If I change the value for the "ASPNETCORE_AzureComputerVisionApiKey" line to be:

```
    "ASPNETCORE_AzureComputerVisionApiKey" = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(${azurerm_key_vault_secret.keyvault-apikey.id})"
```

So that it references the Key Vault secret, I get the following error during a `terraform plan` operation:

```
Error: Cycle: azurerm_app_service.api, azurerm_key_vault.keyvault, azurerm_key_vault_secret.keyvault-apikey
```

Comment: Can you share the Terraform code you've written so far? If it actually errors with a circular dependency then posting the full error would also help people help you.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR, I've updated my questions with both of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your issue, as the error shows, it's a problem about the cyclic dependency.

When you change the `appsettings` in the resource `azurerm_app_service` like this:

```
"ASPNETCORE_AzureComputerVisionApiKey" = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(${azurerm_key_vault_secret.keyvault-apikey.id})"
```

Then the dependency will like this:

**azurerm_key_vault_secret** dependents on **azurerm_key_vault**

**azurerm_key_vault** dependents on **azurerm_app_service**

**azurerm_app_service** dependents on **azurerm_key_vault**

So it shows the error and cannot create all the resources.

The solution is to change the sequence of the creation of resources like this:

1. azurerm_cognitive_account
2. azurerm_key_vault without the access policy
3. azurerm_key_vault_secret
4. azurerm_app_service
5. azurerm_key_vault_access_policy

Just separate the key vault and the key vault access policy, then the cyclic dependency will disappear.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Xu . That works. I was too busy looking for a way to modify the app_service node, that I didn't check the separation of the key_vault settings.

Comment: Good solution - I have however found that seperating the key vault access policies from the key vault has caused errors when TF creates Key Vault secrets (azurerm_key_vault_secret). 

This is happening because it's trying to create a secret prior to an access policy existing for the Service Principal exists to create it. If the access policy is defined within the key vault, it works, but not when defined as a seperate resource (race condition?)

Unfrotunately terraform does not seem to like a mix of access policy within the key vault resource AND a key vault access policy resource.

Comment: @FrancisDean Yes, the policy is first then the secret. Terraform will sequence it rightly.

Comment: @CharlesXu I found it wasn't consistently working when defining the access policies as seperate resources, and Terraform often errored when creating the secret resource because the access policy hadn't been created -with- the key vault (defined in the key_vault resource block). 

Your solution is absolutely correct in principle (& helped me!). The issue I describe is is a terraform bug/oversight/access policy creation delay. Once terraform allows a combination of access_policy in the Key vault resource AND a seperate key_vault_access resource (see TF docs) it will solve my issues.

Comment: @FrancisDean As I said you need to create the policy to allow the service principal you used with the right permission. No matter together or separate. And if separate, you maybe need to set the dependency.